# Dynamically loaded component doesn't work with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular4 and have a component thats loaded dynamically. I'd like to implement the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy but it doesn't seem to work even though I know that the input objects are brand new. I know that normal change detection doesn't work with dynamically loaded components but is there a way to programmatically push the change so that the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush will detect the change?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, no.

Long answer *(I'm sorry, my english is not that good)*, the automatic change detection of `@Input`s is wired when your component is used in a template. Angular compiles it and builds a component factory with the code dealing with this change detection things.

If you want to used a dynamic component, the `@Input`s are no longer used to bind components in their templates.

But... `@Input`s are just public properties of your component, so you can still access and modify them. But the change detection won't detect it.

I see two solutions:

- You can manually run the change detector when you know there is some changes.
- You can use setters instead of direct properties and trigger the change detector in these setters.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as angular4. There is angular and there is a version number https://angular.io/presskit. Yes there is a way. Add an instance of the `ChangeDetectorRef` class to your component and run its `detectChanges()` method when you want to detect changes. This is more of a question you could answer by reading the docs...

Comment: Yeah when google search actually knows the difference I'll stop calling it angular4. I also looked at the docs but thanks for assuming. I was looking in the wrong place.